# How safe is the md5 hashing algorithmic if I know part of the original data

Tags: md5

I'm planning on using an md5 hash to confirm or not a secure operation, part of the hash original data is public, the other part is not:

```
partnerId : fixed 15 chars string (PUBLIC)
amount: int value, from 0 to 6500000 (PUBLIC)
transactionId: string, 5 to 30 chars (PUBLIC)
secure: string, yet to decide how long it needs to be. (PRIVATE)
```

The resulting hash is `md5(partnerId.amount.transactionId.secure);`

The *secure* constant is safe in my partner server and in my server, so in theory we are the only one that can replicate the hash. But I wonder how long needs to be the secure variable in order to keep the hash safe, how long in percentage terms compare to the public part of the hash, 80 private/20 public ? 50 / 50?

Is there maybe an equation to measure this?

Comment: Consider asking this on Information Security Stack Exchange http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: Do you have to use MD5, MD5 is known to be quite weak. Why not just go with SHA256 and not have to worry about it?